Metodo $_POST me llega vacio
Tengo un problema, mi profesora no me lo ha sabido solucionar así que pregunto por aquí.
Hemos hecho un formulario, el problema es que cuando lo ejecuto y le doy a submit en la parte del servidor el POST me llega vacio.
Lo he cambiado a _REQUEST por probar y si funcionaba con ese metodo, sin embargo la profesora lo quiere con POST, así que no se como arreglar este problema.
Ayuda por favor :C
Código html:
`
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ejercicio 19 - 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Buscador de libros</h1>
    <form action="result_libros.php" method="post" >

        <label for="Busqueda">Buscar en: <br> Texto de búsqueda: </label>
        <input type="text" id="Busqueda" name="Busqueda">
        <br>
        
        <label for="op">Buscar en: </label>
        <input type="radio" id="op" name="op" value="Titulo" checked>Título del libro
        <input type="radio" id="op" name="op" value="Autor">Nombre del autor
        <input type="radio" id="op" name="op" value="editorial">Editorial
        <br>

        <label for="tipo">Tipo de libro:</label>
        <select id="tipo" name="tipo">
            <option value="Narrativa">Narrativa</option>
            <option value="Libros">Libros de texto</option>
            <option value="Guias">Guias y mapas</option>
        </select>

        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>

Código php:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ejercicio19 - 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Resultados del formulario de búsqueda</h1>
    <p>Estos son los datos introducidos</p>
    <?php
    print_r($_POST);
    
        if(isset($_POST['Busqueda'])){
            $busqueda=$_POST['Busqueda'];
        }else{
            $busqueda="No ha sido rellenado";
        }
            
        $op=$_POST['op'];
        $Tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
    ?>

    <ul>
        <li>Texto de búsqueda: <?php echo $busqueda ?></li>
        <li>Buscar en: <?php echo $op ?></li>
        <li>Género: <?php echo $Tipo ?></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>


Se me arreglo por arte de magia c:

No hay nada incorrecto con la etiqueta del formulario (hay otros errores de código, pero nada que impida mandar los datos con POST)

No existe la "arte de magia". La programación es una ciencia, el código SIEMPRE se ejecuta de la misma manera. No existen los poltergeist ni la magia...
